# AWS JIRA CloudFormation S3 Access Denied with Default Settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, jira

I'm trying to create JIRA on AWS using CloudFormation by following Atlassian and AWS documentations. However I'm not able to create a JIRA Stack.

[Atlassian Doc](https://developer.atlassian.com/platform/marketplace/dc-apps-performance-toolkit-user-guide-jira-cf/)

[AWS Doc](https://aws-ia.github.io/cfn-ps-atlassian-jira/)

These are the exact steps I'm trying:

1. Go to [this link](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-west-2#/stacks/create?stackName=Jira&templateURL=https://aws-ia-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/cfn-ps-atlassian-jira/templates/quickstart-jira-dc-with-vpc.template.yaml) and click Next
2. Do these changes:

   - Switch version to 8.20.26
   - Set Cluster node instance volume size to 100
   - Switch DB version to 11
   - Enter a master admin password and application user database password
   - Give a key pair name (that is exist on AWS key pairs)
   - Set trusted IP range to 0.0.0.0/0
   - Choose us-west-2a and us-west-2b as availability zones

And click next.

3. Choose the IAM Role with `AdministrationAccess` policy and click next and submit.

This setup gets this error at the very beginning of creation process:

> VPCStack
> CREATE_FAILED
> S3 error: Access Denied For more information check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html

For the investigation, I downloaded the template from the S3 bucket and had a look. I suspected that the `QSS3BucketName` and `QSS3KeyPrefix` are not correct. Even though AWS Doc says do not change them, I gave it a shot.

Since the template URL is "https://aws-ia-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/cfn-ps-atlassian-jira/templates/quickstart-jira-dc-with-vpc.template.yaml", I set the `QSS3BucketName` to `aws-ia-us-east-1` and `QSS3KeyPrefix` to `cfn-ps-atlassian-jira/`.

This resolved the initial error. However, at the very end of the creation process I get this error, when AWS trying to create the Database:

> PostgresDatabase
> CREATE_FAILED
> S3 error: Access Denied For more information check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html

For further investigation, I stopped the stack rollback and tried to update the database. I see that there is a `QSS3BucketRegion` option available on the update, the option doesn't exist on create. This might cause something, but couldn't find a way to fix that.

So, I'm stuck at this point. What am I doing wrong?